# Mongoid Create New Embedded Document Inside Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models I am working with Events and Reports. Reports and embedded in Events. I am having trouble creating a new report for a particular event.

I think my Report Controller new action needs to look something like this:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:eventid])
@report = @event.report.build
```

In my Event model I have the following set:

```
embeds_one :report
accepts_nested_attributes_for :report
```

When I try to save I receive the following error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoParent
```

Here is my Report Model

```
class Report
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
field :test, type: String
embedded_in :event, :inverse_of => :report
embeds_many :report_details
accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_details,
  :allow_destroy => true, 
    :reject_if => proc { |attributes| 
      attributes['name'].blank? && attributes['_destroy'].blank? 
    }
```

And here is my Event Model

```
class Event
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
embeds_one :report
accepts_nested_attributes_for :report,
:allow_destroy => true, 
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| 
    attributes['name'].blank? && attributes['_destroy'].blank? 
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give your model structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to have the `event_id` set on your new report when you're creating it.

You can accomplish this by using `@report = @event.report.build(params[:report])` as you hinted, or by ensuring that 'event_id' is included in the params hash.